# Boot arch linux in efi mode inside of vmware fusion

Tags: vmware, archlinux

When I do ls /sys/firmware/efi there is no file or directory. Everything I looked up on booting in this mode does not help me with the vm. I looked at a link from the vmware website that said to go to vm > settings and enable efi instead of bios, but it is not there for me.

Comment: Did you install the vm booted from a uefi disk?

Answer (score 5):

go to your vmware directory, on mine is ~/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/{Machine Name}.vmwarevm. Edit the file {Machine Name}.vmx and add the line

firmware = "efi"